# Delete files in linux without "No such file and Directory" and "Permissions Denied" errors

Tags: shell, unix, bamboo

I have set up a bamboo job to delete files and folders on a server at a particular location for files/folders older than 15 days and the job runs fine and deletes the files/folders but then the shell command exits with code 1 due to "Permissions denied" and "No such files or directory" errors which are always expected and hence the whole build fails. We want it to report success.
Is there a way to skip these errors and delete files modified older than 15 days for those files only where the shell command can return always 0.

find ./* -type d -ctime +15 -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: Did you try modifying the ownership of the directory you´re working in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exit code of a script is that of its last command, you can add any "true" command in the end. There's `true`, as well as `:` though tricky:

```
find ./* -type d -ctime +15 -exec rm -rf {} \;

: always true here
```

For the explanation of `:`, See [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

`find ./* -type d -ctime +15 -exec rm -rf {} \; || true`